# Erro ao sair do FormShow

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Estou tentando descobri um erro que não sei exatamente onde ele é gerado.
sempre que tenho que abri uma das telas do sistema ele passo por 2 procedure, (vou por elas logo abaixo) a Primeira é o `FormShow` nela eu Chamo a outra que é a `CalculaSaldoHonorario`.

Em `CalculaSaldoHonorario` eu abro uma query e até ai nada ocorre de errado, saindo de `CalculaSaldoHonorario` ele termina o `FormShow` e logo a pois o `end;` da o erro:

> ```
> ---------------------------
> Debugger Exception Notification
> ---------------------------
> Project MeuSistema.exe raised exception class EConvertError with message ''' is not a valid integer value'.
> ---------------------------
> Break   Continue   Help   
> ---------------------------
> ```

Estou utilizando o **UniDAC** no meu projeto.

Segue os códigos:

```
procedure TfrmManutencaoHonorarios.CalculaSaldoHonorario;
var zTotReceber: Currency;
begin
  DataModuleGeral2.dtsVerPagamentos.Enabled := False;
  DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.Close;
  DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.SQL.Clear;

  DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.SQL.Add('select * from PAGAMENTOS T1 where T1.NUMERO_PROCESSO = '+QuotedStr(dbeNumero_Processo.Text)+' order by T1.DATA_PAGTO');
  DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.Open;

  // Soma os Pagamentos
  zTotPagto := 0;
  DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.First;
  while not DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.Eof do
  begin
    zTotPagto := zTotPagto + DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentosVALOR_PAGTO.AsCurrency;
    DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.Next;
  end;

  DataModuleGeral2.qryVerPagamentos.First;

  DataModuleGeral2.dtsVerPagamentos.Enabled := True;

  edtValorTotalPagto.Text := String(RightStr(AnsiString('            '+FormatFloat('#,###,###,##0.00', zTotPagto))  , 14));
  // Encontra o Total a Receber
  zTotReceber := DataModuleGeral.tbHonorariosVALOR_TOTAL.AsCurrency - zTotPagto;
  if zTotReceber < 0 then zTotReceber := 0;
  edtTotalReceber.Text    := String(RightStr(AnsiString('            '+FormatFloat('#,###,###,##0.00', zTotReceber)), 14));

end;
```

Código do `FormShow`

```
procedure TfrmManutencaoHonorarios.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Left :=   0;
  Top  := 144;

  if DataModuleGeral.tbHonorarios.Active = True then
  begin
    DataModuleGeral.tbUsuarios.Open;
    DataModuleGeral.tbHonorarios.Last;
  end;

  VerificaProcessoContrato;

  btnPesquisar.SetFocus;
end; // Logo depois que passa por esse end da o erro!
```

No erro ele abre o fonte do `System.SysUtils`
nesse parte:

```
procedure ConvertErrorFmt(ResString: PResStringRec; const Args: array of const); {$IFDEF ELF} local; {$ENDIF}
begin
  raise EConvertError.CreateResFmt(ResString, Args);
end;
```

Isolei linha a linha dessas duas procedure e botem no passo a passo do *Debug*
o erro só ocorre **se** abre a query, depois que sei de `CalculaSaldoHonorario` não da erro, só da o erro na saída do `OnShow` e não aparece onde passa antes de ir para a procedure do `ConvertErrorFmt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o erro está ocorrendo por conta que, em algum momento de seu Código está requisitando alguma coisa que não esta acessível.

> Isolei a linha dessas duas procedure e botem no passo a passo do
>   Debug o erro só ocorre se abre a query, depois que sai de
>   CalculaSaldoHonorario não da erro, só da o erro na saída do OnShow e
>   não aparece onde passa antes de ir para a procedure do
>   ConvertErrorFmt.

reveja com Calma se nessa procedure/function `CalculaSaldoHonorario` pode ser que nela deva esta lincada com outra rotina que deva está causando o erro ou algum capo que deve está com um tipo de dados declarado e na sua query está outro.

Essa é uma resposta com base nas informações passadas por conta de não tenho dados suficientes para verificar o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem ?

Recomendo o uso de parâmetros no seu método,

```
procedure TfrmManutencaoHonorarios.CalculaSaldoHonorario(const num_processo: integer);
```

Para saber se o número é informado ou não e poder tratar.

Pois acredito que o erro possa estar ai, pois se o `num_processo` ou `dbeNumero_Processo.Text` estiver vazio todo sua lógica e SQL e de negócio  irá falhar na sequencia se não for tratado.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia @Edu Mendonça.. tudo cerretinho..?? :) Cara.. Pelo que posso notar acho que é o seguinte..:

- Obs 01) Dentro da procedure `CalculaSaldoHonorario` quando você abre a Query esta passando o `'+QuotedStr(dbeNumero_Processo.Text)+'`  como parâmetro da Query. Se este objeto estiver vazio.. Irá dar erro.
- Obs 02) Dentro dessa procedure você usa o *DataModuleGeral*. E se não houver Registros? pode dar erro também.

Posso não ter interpretado direito o código.. mas acho que é isso.. :) Quando acertar, posta qual era o erro. :)

Comment: QuotedStr()  Coloca " " no numero do processo para fazer a busca sempre vai ter número de processo.